# Multiplication with first array value returning 0 always

Tags: php, arrays, currency, currency-formatting

I am getting a value from database `67.00€` .I need to multiple this value with an integer. So, used `explode` function of php to convert this to array and stored it in a variable `$result`.

`print_r()` is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 67
    [1] => 00€
)
```

Now, if i'm multiplying the first value of this array with any value, result is always 0.
like:

`$result[0]*12`

i also tried to convert the first value  to integer by using `(int) $result[0]` and `intval($result[0])`. Both output 0

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can anyone explain why i'm getting negative votes?

Comment: Try `var_dump()` or a debugger.

Comment: `var_dump` of `$result[0]` outputs `string 67`where as  `intval($result[0])` outputs `int 0`

Comment: var_dump() should output the byte length of the strings, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
intval($result[0])* 12
```

I have tried this and it worked for me. Please create a new file and run in localhost other that your project.

test.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$str = '67.00$';
$result = explode('.',$str);
print_r($result);

$ans= intval($result[0])*12;    // or  $ans=($result[0])*12;  both worked
echo 'Answer-->'.$ans;   // 804
?>
```

I don't know what you doing wrong. I hope from this you may able to detect your err.

Comment: Tried this as well. Still same result

Comment: edited my answer....please try. Or share your code then will be easy to debug may be you done something wrong. which might be you thinking is correct.

Comment: edited my question for some more info.

Comment: Updated my answer and its working for me. Please check.

Comment: It works statically(like you have stored `67.00$` in `$str`), but not dynamically. I'm getting value from database and on `print_r()`, it displays `67.00$` in browser.